# Elasticsearch - общие вопросы

Tags: elasticcloud, php, elasticsearch

- Как внедрять elasticsearch в веб,
     например для поиска пользователей по
     имени на базе Mysql?
- Как добавлять в    индекс новую
     информацию (например,    если
     зарегистрировался новый 
     пользователь)
- Elastic поддерживает    поиск только
     на основе Restful(URL)    запросов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,2) добавлять данные в индекс (написать обработку + события на изменения)

3) Есть коннекторы на разных языках (я например ковыряю PHP). Их основная проблема, что работают они иначе чем при запросе к HTTP (массивы параметров, итп).
Проблема для меня сейчас - разобраться с анализаторами - из коробки ищет только полные совпадения слов, анализаторы при применении ищут не так, как предполагается в документации.

Answer (score 1):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/122531/

Comment: Видел - их этой статьи много вопросов. Например какие стандарты добавления в индекс, всегда ли нужно добавлять через URL. Там ничего не описано как работать с Mysql

Comment: Не нахожу достойного примера - как добавить в индекс